# How to building own java framework

Tags: java, frameworks

i and my friends make same projects in java. We decided that create own framework. But i don't  know how to follow technical way? how to customize our structure to every project? how to design template engine for example? Should we be independed from other frameworks (spring,struts,ejb etc.) ? we want to develop this structor.i am confused.can you advise me?

Comment: Sorry, but this question appears to be way too broad.

Comment: i just want technical advise to start anything

Comment: If you try to create a framework for every project, you'll end up with a framework that won't be good for any project.

Comment: in every project, i write same code and only changing template.Should we create template engine and back-end is a framework(spring,struts etc)? I don't want same code in same every project.İ just want it

Comment: well, the first thing you need to do a framework is a problem to solve :-) [or several problems to solve]

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, if you're not rich, first thing you need is to identify a niche and have a client to pay for the first development.

After that, you'll have to develop a solution with some nice code architecture that allows you, at the same time, to deliver something nice and that can be customized for other similar clients.

Sometimes, you can even try to deal with your first client to be a partner, providing feedback and helping you getting other clients for you (sometimes, it's a win-win deal and they can help you selling your software if they have the right contacts).

At the same time, you need to have a vision of what your product can do. This mostly depends on your niche characteristics. What backend they use most? What OS? Do they want integration with any other product? Other platforms (mobile for example)?

This is not the developer job, but it's more like a marketing task to be assigned to a product manager, so my tips here are basically

- build something that solves a problem for someone that can pay
- learn about your niche
- try to establish partnerships
- find a good / experienced product manager

Good luck

Comment: thanx to advice. I create own slide gallery,accordion menu, theme etc.. with based javascript. They are my product.In every project, if i need, i put them. So i want that i create own java library or framework.And i have a custom product. Customize project to every customer.Again and again starting same project and writing same code is boring. We have a lof of client.And good experienced project manager.Thanx to reply